# AutoCompleteTextView hide and show dropdown on adapter change

Tags: android

I have an AutoCompleteTextView that gets suggestion from an API with an AsyncTask.
in onPostExecute i create a new adapter, set it to the AutoCompleteTextView and notify data set change to the adapter.

in a TextWatcher I execute the AsyncTask.

everything is working fine except that the dropdown is dismissed and shown every time the adapter is changed.

how can I keep the dropdown open even while the data is changing ?

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                searchPlacesTask.cancel(true);
                searchPlacesTask = new SearchPlacesTask();
                searchPlacesTask.execute(s.toString().replace(" ", "-"));
            } else {
                searchPlacesTask.cancel(true);
                searchPlacesTask = new SearchPlacesTask();
                searchPlacesTask.execute();
            }
        }
    });



private class SearchPlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, PlacesAPIResult> {

    @Override
    protected PlacesAPIResult doInBackground(String... params) {
        PlacesAPIResult result = new PlacesAPIResult();

        if (params.length > 0) {
            places = PlacesAPIRestMethod.placeAutocomplete(params[0], currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), 
                    500, null, result);
        } else {
            places = PlacesAPIRestMethod.placeSearch(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), 0, true, result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PlacesAPIResult result) {
        if (result.getResult() == PlacesAPIResult.OK) {
            adapter = new PlaceAdapter(ChooseLocationActivity.this, R.layout.locationrow, places);
            searchText.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue, but unable to resolve. Please Let me know if you able to fix this.

Comment: Now I am facing the same issue. If you have solution, please let me know

Answer (score 4):

Implements Filterable in adapter, and add this code.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable{


    private List<String> listResult;

    ...
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = listResult;
                    filterResults.count = listResult.size();
                    }
                return filterResults;
                }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't beleive this worked... I don't get it, but you just saved me a few hours of extra work, thanks a lot! For the record, I assigned value to listResult every time I want to refresh my adapter.

Comment: How this works? How it inflates as Dropdown? Can you please explain. Also, how to get the itemclick of dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and handle it this way:

1. Created an external class that extends `ArrayAdapter` and implements `TextWatcher` passing an empty data collection to it.
2. Initiated worker threads similar way you did.
3. Implemented `getFilter()` method. Nothing important done there. Just a stub with `notifyDatachanged()`.
4. Updated adapter's data in `onProgressUpdate`. Should also work in `onPostExecute`. My problem was here. At first I cleared entirely old data and only after that added new. This resulted in "hide and show" effect of dropdown list of items. Then I changed the way I cleared the old data - I removed item by item old data and added item by item new data. That fixed the unwanted effect.

In your case I would suggest to move the construction of `PlaceAdapter` and setting the adapter out from `onPostExecute` and do something like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PlacesAPIResult result) {
        if (result.getResult() == PlacesAPIResult.OK) {
            //TODO: iterate adapter's data and remove every item
            //TODO: iterate `places` collection and add each item to adapter's data
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter()` method accepts instance of class that inherits `ListAdapter` and `Filterable` interfaces.
`Filterable` interface is the key to your issue.

When you type text in `AutoCompleteTextView` it uses `Filter` that returned from `Filterable.getFilter()` method to filter items in dropdown list.

If your `PlaceAdapter` inherits from `ArrayAdapter` then you should notice that `ArrayAdapter` already implements `Filterable` interface and `getFilter()` method returns `ArrayFilter` that in `performFiltering(CharSequence prefix)` method takes current items of `ArrayAdapter`, turns them to lowercase strings with `item.toString().toLowerCase()` and filters only those of them which have words starting with `prefix.toString().toLowerCase()`.

Next I noticed that if `Filter.performFiltering()` method returns `FilterResults` with `FilterResults.count == 0` then dropdown list is hiding.

So if you not overriding `ArrayAdapter.getFilter()` method with your custom filter that executes your `SearchPlacesTask` then you are ending up with dropdown list hiding because of `Filter.performFiltering()` returning zero results and showing when `SearchPlacesTask.onPostExecute()` assigns new adapter and calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Best option is not to use `AsyncTask` and call your API methods right inside `Filter.performFiltering()`:

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final List<Place> items = new ArrayList<Place>();

    // other code
    // ...

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                String query = constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : "";
                List<Place> places;
                PlacesAPIResult result = new PlacesAPIResult();
                if (query.isEmpty()) {
                    places = PlacesAPIRestMethod
                        .placeSearch(currentLocation.getLatitude(), 
                            currentLocation.getLongitude(), 0, true, result);

                } else {
                    places = PlacesAPIRestMethod.placeAutocomplete(query, 
                        currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), 
                        500, null, result);
                }
                if (result.getResult() == PlacesAPIResult.OK) {
                    filterResults.values = places;
                    filterResults.count = places.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                List<Place> places = (List<Place>) results.values;
                if (places != null) {
                    items.clear();
                    items.addAll(places);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If you are forced to use `AsyncTask` then you can execute `SearchPlacesTask` in `Filter.performFiltering()` like `new SearchPlacesTask().execute(query).get()` to synchronously wait until task is finished and return results from `Filter.performFiltering()` method.

`Filter.performFiltering()` method is invoked in worker thread so you should not worry about asynchronous execution of API methods.

`Filter.publishResults()` method is invoked in UI thread and this is the place where you should update adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

`AutoCompleteTextView` manages repeated requests when user changes text faster then new results are loaded and cancels previous requests so implementing `Filterable` in your adapter is the only right way to correctly use `AutoCompleteTextView`.